# validating input string "RX-EZ12345678912345B" using regex

Tags: java, regex, regex-greedy

I need to validate input string which should be in the below format:

```
<2_upper_case_letters><"-"><2_upper_case_letters><14-digit number><1_uppercase_letter>
```

> Ex: RX-EZ12345678912345B

I tried something like this `^[IN]-?[A-Z]{0,2}?\\d{0,14}[A-Z]{0,1}` but its not giving the expected result.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your biggest problem is the `[IN]` at the beginning, which matches only one letter, and only if it's `I` or `N`.  If you want to match two of *any* letters, use `[A-Z]{2}`.

Once you fix that, your regex will still only match `RX-E`.  That's because `[A-Z]{0,2}?` starts out trying to consume nothing, thanks to the reluctant quantifier, `{0,2}?`.  Then `\d{0,14}` matches zero digits, and `[A-Z]{0,1}` greedily consumes the `E`.

If you want to match exactly 2 letters and 14 digits, use `[A-Z]{2}` and `\d{14}`.  And since you're validating the string, you should end the regex with the end anchor, `$`.  Result:

```
^[A-Z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}\d{14}[A-Z]$
```

...or, as a Java string literal:

```
"^[A-Z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}\\d{14}[A-Z]$"
```

As @nhahtdh observed, you don't really have to use the anchors if you're using Java's `matches()` method to apply the regex, but I recommend doing so anyway.  It communicates your intent better, and it makes the regex portable, in case you have to use it in a different flavor/context.

**EDIT:** If the first two characters should be exactly `IN`, it would be

```
^IN-[A-Z]{2}\d{14}[A-Z]$
```

Comment: Thanks Alan, [A-Z]{2} at the beginning matches any two characters, is there a way to restrict first character to be 'I' and second one 'N'?

Comment: See my edit.  But if it's supposed to start with `IN`, why did you provide an exemplar that starts with `RX`?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to do at the beginning of your current regex.

```
"^[A-Z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}\\d{14}[A-Z]$"
```

The regex above will strictly match the input string as you specified. If you use `matches` function, `^` and `$` may be omitted.

Since you want exact number of repetitions, you should specify it as `{<number>}` only. `{<number>,<number>}` is used for variable number of repetitions. And `?` specify that the token before may or may **not** appear - if it must be there, then specifying `?` is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Simply translating your requirements into a java regex:

```
"^[A-Z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}\\d{14}[A-Z]$"
```

This will allow you to use:

```
if (!input.matches("^[A-Z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}\\d{14}[A-Z]$")) {
    // do something because input is invalid
}
```

Comment: Hi nhahtdh, Bohemian, this regex worked, except that i need to restict the first two character to 'IN', i changed regex to ^[IN]{2}-[A-Z]{2}\\d{14}[A-Z]$ but it return true even for 'NI'?

Answer (score 1):

`^[A-Z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}\\d{14}[A-Z]$`

This should solve your purpose. You can confirm it from [here](http://regexpal.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem. Check out the validity [here](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/)

```
^[A-Z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{14}[A-Z]$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^([A-Z]{2,2}[-]{1,1}[A-Z]{2,2}[0-9]{14,14}[A-Z]{1,1}){1,1}$
```

Comment: What's this `{1,1}`, `{2,2}` stuff?  If you want to consume exactly 2 or 14 of something, `{2}` or `{14}` is all you need.  (In fact, I wouldn't be surprised if some flavors treat the long version as a syntax error.)  As for `{1,1}`, don't bother shortening it, just get rid of it.  All you're doing is telling the regex engine to consume one of the preceding atom, which is what it was going to do anyway.

Comment: specified range{min,max} I got this from egrep where for example  {0,1} are equivalent to ?. But i understood that this is quite outdated now.Thx for correcting me